# How to construct a continuous and not monotonic that is close as required to a given function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous and monotonic function. Given $r>0$, I would like to construct a continuous function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that

1. $g$ is NOT monotonic.
2. $\max_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)| < r$.

The intuition is clear as I draw in the picture. But I fail to construct such required function.

[image]

Could you please shed me some light? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you require $g(x)<f(x)$ on $(0,1)$ ? But why not $g(x)=f(0)+\frac{r}{2}$ on $[0,y]$ where $y$ is the smallest element s.t. $|f(y)-f(0)|\geq \frac{r}{2}$ and then $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{r}{2}$ on $[y,u]$ where $u<1$ and then linear on $[u,1]$ s.t. $g(1)=f(1)$. If $f$ is of the form $ax+b$ we have to change a bit the construction...

Comment: Hi @Surb, I don't required $f(x)<g(x)$ on $[0,1]$. I quite confused with your comment since I define $g$ from a given $f$. It seems that you define $f$ from $g$.

Comment: @Surb, My ultimate goal is to prove that given a continuous and monotonic function $f$ on $[0,1]$ and $r>0$, there exists a continuous and not monotonic function $g$ such that $\max_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)| < r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sufficiently high $K$, $$g(x) = f(x) + \frac r2 \sin Kx$$
should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elegant approach :)))